# Modifying Eval("data") as it populates to the gridview

Tags: asp.net

I'm tasked with changing an older website and adding functionality of a third party API. For this API to work, some data from the database must be modified based on certain conditions.

The code is as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="AccLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Acc") %>' Width="96px"/>
```

The data in the database has this field in a variety of formats depending on the table. For example's sake, we'll say A1965445.  Currently the website shows that format for the data, however for the API to accept the query, the data needs to be in the following format: A19-65445

Different tables in the database will have hyphens at different locations.

I don't want the data changed in the database, only for the user on the website. The API call just looks at the rows on the current page before making the call.

Thank you

Comment: Just so I'm clear: the data might be stored as A1965445 or A1-965445 or sometimes A19654-45, but you always want to display it as A19-65445?

Comment: It is always without hyphens in the database. But I want it displayed by logic I'll add in. In the example, A19-12345 is the format we want.

Comment: @user608293 Then what did you mean by _"Different tables in the database will have hyphens at different locations."_? Is this referring to the output in your gridview?

Comment: You can [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) it any way you want.

Comment: @wazz is right. It sounds like you just need a format mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Eval("Acc").ToString().Substring(0, 2) + "-" + Eval("Acc").ToString().Substring(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.ToString()` and then do simple string manipulation on the value. I would insert the dash character at the specific index you need it (in your sample: `2`):

```
<asp:Label ID="AccLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Acc").ToString().Trim().Insert(2, "-") %>' 
           Width="96px" />
```

If you need to move the dash (ex: `A1965-445` to `A19-65445`) then remove all dashes and insert the one you want:

```
Eval("Acc").ToString().Trim().Remove("-", "").Insert(2, "-")
```

Comment: unfortunately the site throws a 404 with this method.